# SAP Hard-coded logon parameters not allowed when using a Destination Configuration in C#

Tags: c#, sap-dotnet-connector

When I try to connect to SAP server dynamically I am getting error like

Hard-coded logon parameters not allowed when using a Destination Configuration

any one plz help me

I need to send all parameters from codebehind Dynamically not from Web.config

from web.config its working fine .. but not here

My code is like this

```
            SAPSystemConnect objSapConfig = new SAPSystemConnect();
            RfcDestination objSapdestination = null;

            RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(objSapConfig);

            RfcConfigParameters objParameter = new RfcConfigParameters();
            objParameter.Add(RfcConfigParameters.AppServerHost, Convert.ToString("XXX"));
            objParameter.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Client, Convert.ToString("XXX"));
            objParameter.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Password, Convert.ToString("XXX"));
            objParameter.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemNumber, Convert.ToString("XXX"));
            objParameter.Add(RfcConfigParameters.User, Convert.ToString("XXX"));
            objParameter.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Language, Convert.ToString("XXX"));
            objParameter.Add(RfcConfigParameters.LogonGroup, Convert.ToString("XXX"));

            objParameter.Add(RfcConfigParameters.PoolSize, Convert.ToString("XXX"));
            objParameter.Add(RfcConfigParameters.PeakConnectionsLimit, Convert.ToString("5"));
            objParameter.Add(RfcConfigParameters.IdleTimeout, Convert.ToString("XXX"));
            //objParameter.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Name, Convert.ToString("XXX"));


          
            objSapdestination = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination(objParameter);
            RfcCustomDestination customDest = objSapdestination.CreateCustomDestination();
            IRfcFunction func = customDest.Repository.CreateFunction("XXX");

           
        

            RfcRepository objSapRepository = objSapdestination.Repository;

            // Calling Sap Function
            IRfcFunction objSapDataFunction = objSapRepository.CreateFunction(Convert.ToString("XXX"));

            objSapDataFunction.SetValue("XXX", "XXX");

            objSapDataFunction.Invoke(objSapdestination);

            // Filling SapData into Table
            IRfcTable objSapTable = objSapDataFunction.GetTable(Convert.ToString("GIT_DATA"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Check this out. This is a just a demo code.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SapConnection con = new SapConnection();
        RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(con);
        RfcDestination dest = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("NSP");
        RfcRepository repo = dest.Repository;

        IRfcFunction fReadTable = repo.CreateFunction("ZSOMA");
        fReadTable.SetValue("I_NRO1", 1);
        fReadTable.SetValue("I_NRO2", 2);


        fReadTable.Invoke(dest);
        var result = fReadTable.GetValue("E_RESULT");

        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class SapConnection : IDestinationConfiguration
{
    public RfcConfigParameters GetParameters(string destinationName)
    {
        RfcConfigParameters conf = new RfcConfigParameters();
        if (destinationName == "NSP")
        {
            conf.Add(RfcConfigParameters.AppServerHost, "sap-vm");
            conf.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemNumber, "00");
            conf.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemID, "xxx");
            conf.Add(RfcConfigParameters.User, "yourusername");
            conf.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Password, "yourpassword");
            conf.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Client, "001");
        }
        return conf;
    }

    public bool ChangeEventsSupported()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event RfcDestinationManager.ConfigurationChangeHandler ConfigurationChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prompt the user for the password in this case. I would use a dialog box that masks the text with a password character.

```
Dim value As String

value = InputBox("Security Check", " Enter password", "*")

objParameter.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Password, Convert.ToString(value))
```