# How do I perform a logon with SAP .NET Connector without Hard-coding the password?

Tags: .net, vb.net, sap-dotnet-connector

I am writing an Application in VB.net and use SAP trough an RFC-user. I'm currently trying to improve the security of the application. So now the question I'm asking is: How do I perform a logon with the SAP .NET connector without hard-coding the password?. I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442323/sap-hard-coded-logon-parameters-not-allowed-when-using-a-destination-configurati), which wasn't really helpful. Google found no helpful results too. My intention is to prevent someone from finding out about username and password through simple debugging etc.

```
    strIP = "192.168.0.1"
    strSysNum = "00"
    strSysID = "KE2"
    strMandant = "210"
    strUser = "rfcUser"
    strPSW = "password"
    strLan = "DE"
    strPool = "10"
    strConLimit = "15"
    strConTO = "600"

    parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.AppServerHost, strIP)
    parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemNumber, strSysNum)
    parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemID, strSysID)
    parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.User, strUser)
    parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Password, strPSW)
    parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Client, strMandant)
    parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Language, strLan)
    parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.PoolSize, strPool)
    parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.PeakConnectionsLimit, strConLimit)
    parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.ConnectionIdleTimeout, strConTO)
```

Do you know how I could store/submit the login data without hard-coding it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

So, you are looking to create a simple username/password input box, in vb.net.

As you know, setting the constants as you did works just fine. So, all you need to do is set it equal to some sort of user input, instead of `strPSW = "password"`. The easiest way is to simply replace that line with `strPSW = = InputBox("password, please", "This is the InputBox for typing in passwords.", "*")` You can do something similar with the `strUser` as well.

Now, if you want to store the username and password somewhere, and run the whole thing as a console application that doesn't require any user input, it starts to get a little trickier. You could use the App.config file, an external flat file, or several other methods, and the various methods for encoding/encrypting vary based upon which file you use. In this case, the SAP constraints have nothing to do with your problem. I suggest searching for password encryption in .Net, and finding your favorite method, based upon environment and learning curve.